# getting error &#039 in yii2 advance

Tags: php, yii2

> Exception 'yii\base\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Response content must not be an array.'
> in C:\xampp1\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Response.php:1054

Stack trace:

> ## 0 C:\xampp1\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Response.php(337): yii\web\Response->prepare()
>
> ## 1 C:\xampp1\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(392): yii\web\Response->send()
>
> ## 2 C:\xampp1\htdocs\advanced\frontend\web\index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
>
> ## 3 {main}

```
SiteController.php

public function actionGetuser()
    {
        $model = new UsersData();
        if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
            $id =  Yii::$app->request->post();
              return $model->get($id);
        } 
    }


model:-
function get($id)
    {
        $model = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM user where id=$id");
        return  $user = $model->queryOne();
    }
```

Comment: Right now, your code is open to **sql injection**, every request for get user data can do something **really really bad**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yii2 ActiveRecord findBySql - Response content must not be an array Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120470/yii2-activerecord-findbysql-response-content-must-not-be-an-array-error)

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution :-

```
model:-
     function get($id)
        {
            $userid = json_decode($id);
            $uid = $userid->id;
            $model = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM user where id = $uid");
            $user = $model->queryOne();
            //return $user;
            return  json_encode($user);
        }

controller:-
 public function actionGetuser()
    {
        $model = new UsersData();
        //return "Dfasdafsd";
        if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
            $data =  Yii::$app->request->post();
            $id = json_encode($data);
            return $model->get($id);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change format of your response :

**You can modify its configuration by adding an array to your application config under components as it is shown in the following example:**

```
'response' => [
    'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
    'charset' => 'UTF-8',
    // ...
]
```

[Check This Link For More info](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html)

**OR**

```
function get($id)
   $result = user::find()->where(['id' => $id])->all();
   return Json::encode($result);
}
```